# My Magento Website Not Working On Xampp

Tags: error

```
After uploading backup in xampp magento gives following error.


> a:5:{i:0;s:167:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
    > Table 'blingers.index_process' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT
    > `index_process`.`indexer_code` FROM `index_process`";i:1;s:1525:"#0
    > C:\xampp\htdocs\blingers\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110):
    > Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    > #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\blingers\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
    > #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\blingers\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
    > #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\blingers\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `index_p...', Array)
    > #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\blingers\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `index_p...', Array)
    > #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\blingers\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(794): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
    > #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\blingers\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Resource\Setup.php(66):
    > Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchCol(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
    > #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\blingers\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Resource\Setup.php(45):
    > Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Setup->_syncIndexes()
    > #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\blingers\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235):
    > Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
    > #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\blingers\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(428):
    > Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
    > #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\blingers\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354):
    > Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
    > #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\blingers\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    > #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\blingers\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
    > #13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:10:"/blingers/";s:11:"script_name";s:19:"/blingers/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default
```

";}

Comment: are yo sure your db imported ok as the error is indicating missing tables

Comment: this table not exist blingers.index_process check your db Import Sucessfully or not

Comment: ok I will check

Comment: May be problem with prefix.